# Google Cloud Vision getting Invalid value at 'requests[0].image.content'

Tags: angularjs, google-cloud-vision

I am getting this error:

```
Invalid value at 'requests[0].image.content' (TYPE_BYTES), "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgwSExIQEw8QEBD/...
```

The image is encoded properly (it works using another visual search service that requires the same base64 encoding, metamind), what's wrong with this call?

This is from AngularJS `$http` service:

```
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                data: '{"requests":[{"image":{"content":"' + base64Img + '"},"features":[{"type":"LABEL_DETECTION","maxResults":1}]}]}',
                url: "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=mykey27272772277227292992929"
            }).success(function (result) {
                console.log("SUCCESS");
                $scope.results = result;
                console.log(result);
            }).error(function (err) {
                console.log("FAIL");
                console.log(err);
            });
```

Any idea?

Comment: I just realized they dont want the "data:image/jpeg;base64," part so a base64Img.slice(23) did the job

Comment: You should post that as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

I just realized they dont want the "data:image/jpeg;base64," part so a base64Img.slice(23) did the job

**Update**: Since slice cuts off at the character level `.slice(23)` works perfectly for .png & .jpg (and other types with 3 character extensions) but if a user uploads a type 'jpeg' the extra character ruins your data:

```
var headerless = "data:image/jpeg;base64" 
headerless.slice(23)
```

This would output: `"data:image/jpeg;base6"` and the remaining 4 would corrupt your data.

I'd recommend using `.replace` with a regex statement instead to cover this use case:

```
var image = <my image in b64 including header goes here>
var noHeader = image.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg);base64,/, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

you could directly use jpg format with GCV. The following worked for me:

```
var source = 'http://www.abhishek.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/6-ID-Card-for-Downtown-Motors-Pvt-Limited.jpg';
  var apikey = 'yourkeyXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxx';
  $scope.param = '{"requests": [ { "image": { "source": { "imageUri": "' + source + '" } }, "features": [ { "type": "TEXT_DETECTION" } ] } ] }';
  $scope.url = 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=' + apikey;
  var url = $scope.url;
  var data = $scope.param;
  var config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
  };
  $http.post(url, data,config).then(
    function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    },
    function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });

  })
```