# What are the correct params for Google Cloud Vision JSON Data

Tags: json, bash, google-cloud-vision

I'm getting this error:

`error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid value at 'requests[0].image.content' (TYPE_BYTES), \"000002.jpg\"", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "details": [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest"`

And it may have something to do with the encoding of the images, not sure.  I am sending Google a bunch of `.jpg`s.

Note that this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35925120/google-cloud-vision-getting-invalid-value-at-requests0-image-content), but that one doesn't help a whole lot - there's no answer.

Here's my JSON:

`for f in $FILES
  do
    echo "Original file name is $f"
    response=$(curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type:

    application/json" -X POST -d '{"requests":[
       {
         "image":{
         "content":"'"$f"'"
       },
      "features":[
        {
          "type":"LABEL_DETECTION",
          "maxResults":3
        }
      ]
    }]}' $baseURL)
    echo $response
done`

This is the first image I send it. [image]

Any thoughts on what's causing this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the base64 encoded representation of the image, not the filename.